# html2canvas, a way to catch an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, html2canvas

I need to do a snapshot of an iframe, but html2canvass do not do this, and this is well know.

I tried to pass to html2canvas function the content of the iframe, with `myiframe.contentWindow.document.body` element, this work only if both my page and the page inside the iframe is in the same domain (security reason), but is exactly what i need.

```
html2canvas(divToShare.contentWindow.document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        screenshot = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
};
```

But now come problems....
The output image is not very similar to the to the expectations. buttons look like a textfield and other strange things...
An exemple:

An image of the original page

[image]

And this is the png result from html2canvas, different buttons and text-box and also no background.

[image]

Do I do something wrong? or is normal that the image renderer is not exactly the same?
I just need to take a snapshot of an iframe, if you have another way to do this it's ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because html2canvas work only on the user sider but no the server side. And the CSS of the page in the iframe can not be rendered.

Comment: i know you can't post comments yet, but please avoid posting comment-like answers

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in web developing and also in stackoverflow. How can I avoid posting comment-like answers? Add image or code or something? Please tell me. And if you know the answer of the question, please tell me, too. I don't know wether my answer is true but I realy want to know the real answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, answers on StackOverflow are supposed to completely answer the question. They are supposed to have a definite answer that provides a clear and obvious explanation/solution. Comments are used for discussion to help figure out the answer. This answer, for example, uses words like "maybe", which implies you aren't sure about the answer and if that's actually the problem. That belongs in a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll improve my answer-ability in StackOverFlow.